# performance affected by constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta8

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I added some animations to my app using motion layout, for that I had to change the constraint-layout version from 1.1.3 (which is the stable version) to 2.0.0-beta8 (also tried with beta3, beta6 and beta7).

The animation works as expected but sometimes the rest of the app is getting too laggy, the performance when scrolling views or recyclerViews just gets horrible.

To rule out that the problem was not a bad implementation of the motion layouts, I tried to go back to the previous version of my app (without the animations),  and the performance was good again.. Then I only did the update of the version of the constraint layout (to beta8 again), and realize that this was the cause of poor performance.

Does anyone facing the same problem? Is there a solution for this or we just have to wait for another release? :(

```
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.5
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2014M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.services.firebase, com.hr.dimenify, io.flutter, wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin
```